# Maximum singular value of a matrix valued function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Let $f$ be an analytic matrix-valued function, $\Lambda(A)$ be the spectrum of $A$ and $\sigma_1(A)$ the maximum singular value of $A$.
It is known that

$$\Lambda(f(A)) = f(\Lambda(A)) := \{f(\Lambda) : \lambda \in \Lambda(A) \}$$

Although a similar relation is not valid in general for singular values, numerical experiments suggest that the following inequality holds for the maximum singular value of $A$:

$$ \sigma_{1}( f(A) ) \le f(\sigma_{1}(A)). $$

1. Is this inequality true?
2. Other inequalities of these type also hold for the other singular values?

Comment: Easy counterexample: $f(x) = -1$

Comment: However, there are interesting things to say if $f$ is a power series whose coefficients are all positive

Comment: Ops... missed that counterexample! Thanks for pointing it :)
Is the inequality true if $f$ is a a power series whose coefficients are all positive?

Comment: Yep! Non-negative, if you prefer (can be zero).

Comment: If that's interesting to you, I can put a proof up tomorrow

Comment: Thanks, it would be very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\| \cdot \|$ denote any [sub-multiplicative matrix-norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm).  Let $f(x)$ be given by
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k
$$
where $a_k \geq 0$.  We then have
$$
\|f(A)\| = 
\left\|\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k A^k\right\| \leq
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \|a_k A^k\| =
\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k \|A^k\| \leq
\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k \|A\|^k = f(\|A\|)
$$
Some examples of $\|\cdot\|$ that work here:

- **spectral norm**: $\|A\|=$ largest singular value of $A$
- **Ky-Fan $k$-norm**: $\|A\|=$ sum of $k$ largest singular values of $A$
- **Schatten $p$-norm**: see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm).

So, the inequality may not hold for other singular values (I don't think it will), but it will work for other matrix norms, such as the examples that I've provided.